# Spring cleaning: help us clean up our locked questions on SO

Tags: discussion, status-completed, locked

A few weeks ago we introduced "lock reasons"

[image: reasons]

We have three valid reasons to lock a post:

[image: reasons]

Moderators may lock a post permanently or temporarily.

**Locks are atomic**: as soon as a post is locked, it automatically becomes a relic-in-time that will never be updated or voted on. It is stronger than a close, since the community cannot unlock.

As it stands we have upwards of 240 "historical locks": https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=locked&filter=other where moderators locked the post in the past, prior to the notice feature.

We would like to ensure that all locked posts now have a **valid reason** for the lock or are unlocked/deleted/opened.

---

Can you help us clean up [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=locked&filter=other)?

- Moderators: can you unlock/delete/relock with notice as you see fit?
- Community: can you flag any of the reasonless locked posts with your suggested action?

Comment: Don't know how difficult this is to implement, but if someone selects the "Historical Significance" option, the duration should automatically default to "permanent."  "Content Dispute" should default to 1 day.

Comment: I can special case it I guess

Comment: I was about to make a comment that it's Fall now, before I realized you're from upside down country...

Comment: And btw, if the "Historical reasons" is selected, could you make it such that it automatically locks _all_ the answers too? Right now locking a question doesn't affect the answer...

Comment: I cleaned up all of the questions, maybe someone else can do the answers after you put in your verbiage change.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked donzens but only flagged one :(

Should too-many-edited posts be unlocked? Just asking because we ran the risk of them being massively edited again...

Comment: The locking for excessive editing is for a "cool-off" period, and is supposed to be temporary.